# Why vector is not updating with the new values

Tags: r, vector

I think this is a really silly question, but I can not figure this out by myself, so I thought that I should ask you guys, before hitting my head on the wall repeatedly. Can you explain me why this vector seems to add the new value, but then it stays the same? How can I make it work?

```
cassa = c(1000)

update_cassa = function() {
 ultimo_indice = length(cassa)
 cassa[ultimo_indice + 1] = cassa[ultimo_indice] + 10 
}

for (i in 1:5) {
 update_cassa()
}

print(cassa)
```

I expect the vector "cassa" to be 1000 1010 1020 1030 1040 1050, but the last print statement prints 1000, it seems like no new value has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `cassa` to `update_cassa` function and save the updated values in `cassa` again.

```
cassa = 1000

update_cassa = function(cassa) {
   ultimo_indice = length(cassa)
   cassa[ultimo_indice + 1] = cassa[ultimo_indice] + 10 
   return(cassa)
}

for (i in 1:5) {
   cassa <- update_cassa(cassa)
}

cassa
#[1] 1000 1010 1020 1030 1040 1050
```

I assume this is just an example otherwise there are a lot of non-loop solution to achieve the same output like :

```
1000 + 10 * 0:5
```